# Rails app returning record for a belongs_to association which shouldn't exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Currently experiencing two very strange bugs in a rails 3.2 application with a MySQL database.

There is a model "things" which belongs_to a "parent_thing". This is an optional association and a majority of the time it is expected to be nil.

In the view there are various blocks like the following:

```
if thing.parent_thing then
- show part of the view specific to things with parents
```

(we've also tried if !thing.parent_thing.nil? and a lot of other variants, none of which seems to impact the below behaviour).

In local development mode and the staging environment on Heroku, this functions exactly as expected. In production on Heroku running on 4 Dyno's, it works about 70% of the time but every now and then it seems to toggle into a mode where calls to thing.parent_thing will always return a parent, apparently irrespective of whether one has been set.

This behaviour occurs at seemingly random times but once it has begun occurring it will generally do so for several hours across the system. The system will then eventually revert back to expected behaviour. Restarting all Heroku dyno's does not consistently solve the problem. Logging in with a rails console and inspecting the relevant "thing" entries yields completely normal behaviour.

To try and understand this behaviour we've added logging to production which sends us the results of thing.inspect and thing.parent_thing.inspect whenever the error condition is occurring. This shows thing.parent_thing_id as nil (which is correct) but thing.parent_thing returns a parent regardless.

In addition to the above, when trying to implement further debugging we encountered the following:

At the top of a view we created a variable lines_when_parent_thing_exists = [] which is an array we populate with strings indicating line numbers where thing.parent_thing is returning a parent

This is followed by a call to our logging function which looks like this:

```
send_log_event({:message => "Lines where parent is returned", 
    :data => lines_when_parent_thing_exists.to_s}) 
    unless lines_when_parent_thing_exists.empty?
```

The above send_log_event call is made regardless of whether the array is empty, so we have hundreds of log entries where data is []

This occurs continually rather than just when the first problem is occurring, I include this as I'm not sure if it may give clues as to the first problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing the above?

Comment: This sounds very much like a cache problem. Could it be an issue where cache data isn't being properly invalidated? Do you define `parent_thing` in your `Thing` model, perhaps returning an invalid result?

Comment: As far as we know there's no manual caching in place on any of the affected code, could this be related to activerecords built in caching? parent_thing is defined in thing as a has_many association with a foreign key of parent_thing_id. I don't think it's returning invalid results because it works without issue in dev/ staging?

Comment: Try turning caching on in development and see if you can replicate it. Your first points of debugging will be the differences between dev and prod, and that's generally asset compilation (which doesn't apply here) and caching (which certainly does!)

Comment: Can't seem to replicate it with caching turned on in development mode and the bug doesn't seem to occur on the Heroku staging environment which is running an identical configuration to production. Any ideas where else we could look?